# what does Maven Emma mean with: $SWITCH_TABLE$

Tags: java, maven, emma

I get almost 100% coverage reported by emma for my java code, except for a chunk of lines in one class (which are not highlighted, only the class itself is highlighted).

The 'method' in question is listed as:

```
$SWITCH_TABLE$com$ ...STUFF... (): int []
```

What is this possibly referring to? It seems to be some sort of auto-generated method, which I can't trace to any actual code lines/can't figure out how to test it, etc.

help please. :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a closer look on `STUFF`, it should be an enum.

## Table switch for enums

When you write a switch on an enum like:

```
STUFF stuff;
public String getWho() {
    switch(this.stuff) {
        case THINGIE: return "kid";
        case MATERIAL: return "scientist";
        default: return "people";
    }
}
```

The compiler generates the switch table based on `Enum.ordinal`, that "generation" is done in a method which is called within the `switch`, like:

```
switch( ($SWITCH_TABLE$com$...STUFF...())[this.stuff.ordinal] )
```

Maybe you've only covered that method partially. If you only test `getWho()` once, the generated method misses a branch, because the returned `int[]` is lazy initialized.
The other possibility is that the `catch`es inside the generated method are not covered, but you can't do anything about that.

## Sources and variants

My main source is [this article on enum](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue161.html) and playing around with [JAD](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/decompile-class-file-java-decompiler-class-java-class/) (I suggest the following parameters: `-a -dead -noconv -nocast -noclass -v`).

The article mentions `$SwitchMap$` which is almost the same as `$SWITCH_TABLE$` except the `static intializer` in an inner class is used inside the method. This may be due to an older version of Java or compiler differences.

## 100%

If you are really determined to reach 100% you can hack around and just call it via reflection:

```
@Test
public void testSwitches() {
    for(Method m : NotCovered.class) {
        if(m.getName().startsWith("$SWITCH_TABLE$")) {
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(null); // one for lazy init
            m.invoke(null); // one for quick returning the initialized value
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't try this code nor suggest to use it, just an example.

In my early days I've tried once to reach 100% in a professional environment and for the last 12 percent I needed a lot of test coding and mocking. For the last 3 percent I needed `PowerMock` and some reflection. I think this is another reason why they usually [set the bar at 80-90%](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestCoverage.html).

Comment: I got it from `.getClass().getDeclaredFields()`, I need to skip it, I found no other precise way to do that, so I guess `.getName().startsWith("$SWITCH_TABLE$")` is the best choice right?  and thx! :)

Comment: I would go with [`field.isSynthetic()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldModifiers.html) or something from [`Modifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html). Synthetic also skips `access$000()` and others that you're likely not interested in.

Comment: oh, cool, yes I did need to skip this$0 too, may work I guess! on the description they only say "return if it is synthetic" w/e lol, had no patience to research w/e it means, will do now thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

Emma can complain about sections of code you won't expect to ever be executed. In this case I suspect you have a bridging method which doesn't need to be called.

e.g.

```
class A<N extends Number> {
    void method(N n) { }
}

class B extends A<Integer> {
    void method(Integer n) { }
}
```

In this case, class B has two methods. One is `void method(Integer)` but this doesn't override the one in A from the JVMs perspective, it overloads it so there is another "bridge" method which is generated i.e. `void method(Number n) { method((Integer) n); }`

Comment: awwww, cool.  I'll take a look, it is an extends situation so it might be something like that. :)